# Is it possible to host a express and socket.io app on Firebase Hosting?

Tags: node.js, firebase, socket.io, firebase-hosting

I've been following Firebase cloud functions for a while now. Recently I came across hosting Node.js apps on Firebase Hosting, but it was using just express.

Can we host socket.io apps on Firebase?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Firebase employee here*

This is not possible with Firebase Hosting, even if it's hooked up to Cloud Functions to provide a backend.

If you want realtime socket communication between clients, consider using Realtime Database as a conduit between them.  You'll get more done, write less code, and scale easier this way.

Comment: @MilanNz What is "it" in your comment? Using Firebase's realtime database to communication between clients is not only possible, it's the intended and most common use-case. If you had problems implementing communication between clients on Firebase's realtime database, elaborate please.

Comment: We are already using RTDB, but we wanted socket.io for a entirely different purpose. Now I think I'll have to go back to AWS again.

I'll try and dig in for a while before accepting this answer. Thank you!

Comment: Let me assure you, with Firebase products, it is currently not possible to keep an open socket, whose bidirectional contents you control, open for an indefinite amount of time.  You can 1) serve static content and 2) rewrite URLs to be handled by Cloud Functions via Express.  Your Cloud Functions can not possibly run for more than 9 minutes (default 60s), and you can't control them bidirectionally.  (Note: I work at Google with the Firebase team.)

Comment: @DougStevenson Your new edit made me stop looking at anywhere else, lol. Thank you for your response!

Comment: Is this still not possible to host `Websocket and Nodejs` app on Firebase hosting ?