# Firebase deployment not accepting WebSocket connections

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, sockets, websocket

I have a website that requires a constant socket connection between the client and the server, I'm using Node for this. My server sets up a server using **ws** and then the client connects to it, this all works fine on **localhost**, but it's not working at all when I actually deploy the app to Firebase.

The client and server communicate on port *8080*, I suspect that I need to somehow expose the port on the Firebase server, but I'm not sure that's even the problem.

I've tried using different ports, and different IPs to connect to, all failing. I've tried also using Firebase Functions, but to no avail either.

Here is the WebSocket part of my **server.js**

```
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 })

wss.on("connection", (ws) => {
    ws.on("error", console.error);

    getCount().then(count => {
        ws.send(count);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })

    ws.on("message", (data) => {
        console.log("received " + data);
        if (data >= 120) {
            console.log("not using " + data);
            return;
        }
        
        getCount().then(count => {
            let total = count + parseInt(data);
            ws.send(total);
            writeCount(total);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    });
});
```

Here is the WebSocket part of my **index.js**

```
const protocol = window.location.protocol.includes('https') ? 'wss': 'ws'
const wsAddress = `${protocol}://SERVERIP:8080`;
```

```
function initalizeSocket() {
    socket = new WebSocket(wsAddress);
    console.log(socket);
    console.log(isOpen(socket));
    let first = true;

    socket.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
        globalCounter = Number(event.data);

        if (!first) {
            updateGlobalElement(500);
        }
        else {
            updateGlobalElement(0);
            first = false;
        }

    })
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you deployed your web site to Cloud Functions for Firebase, which is not well suited for hosting web sites that want to accept long-lived processes such as a site that keeps a web socket open. Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45741284/run-a-web-socket-on-cloud-functions-for-firebase, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56903043/is-it-a-good-idea-to-run-socket-io-on-a-firebase-cloud-function?

Comment: You're absolutely right, I didn't check if the connections were persisting, thank you so much for that insight. I was going to initially choose GCloud to host, but I couldn't pay due to their service not supporting my country's currency, that's why I ended up on Firebase.