# Realtime update with Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create a chat in react using firebase cloud functions, but I am not getting any updates when an user send a message. This is my code:

```
const
  app = admin.apps.length ? admin.app() : admin.initializeApp(),
  db = admin.database( app ),
  getMessagesForConversationFn2 = (conversationId: string): Promise<any[]> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const messagesRef = db.ref(`chat/messages/${conversationId}`);
      const messages: any[] = [];

      const onChildAdded = (childSnapshot: admin.database.DataSnapshot) => {
        const eventObject = childSnapshot.val();
        messages.push(eventObject);
        resolve(messages);
      };

      messagesRef.on("child_added", onChildAdded);
    });
  },
  getMessagesForConversationCallback = async ( data: {conversationId: string, unsubscribe: boolean }) => {
    const insideFn = async () => {
      if ( typeof data.conversationId === "undefined" ) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError( "failed-precondition", "Conversation Id Missing" );
      }
      const result = await getMessagesForConversationFn2(data.conversationId);
      return result;
    };
    return new Promise(( res, rej )=>{
      res( insideFn() );
    });
  };
const getMessagesForConversation = functions.https.onCall(getMessagesForConversationCallback);
exports.getMessagesForConversation = getMessagesForConversation;
```

And in my react application I have this:

```
 this.getMessagesForConversation = httpsCallable ( this.functions, "getMessagesForConversation");window.getTeamBilling = this.getMessagesForConversation;

  const getMessagesForConversation = async () => {
    try{
      const resp = await firebase.getMessagesForConversation({
        conversationId: activeChatId,
        unsubscribe: false
      });
      setActiveChatMessages(resp.data.map((msg) => ({message: msg.m, sendTime: msg.d, sender: msg.n, senderId: msg.s})));
    }catch( err ){
      setActiveChatMessages([]);
      console.log( err );
    }
  };
```

I get all the message correctly but In order to get updates I have to call the function again, I would like that when the user b send me a message the messages get updated automatically.

I tried to remove the promise because I thought it might stop the stream but without the promise in the first function I don't get any data at all!

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Functions are most useful for relatively short-lived processes. While nowadays a single call can be active for up to 60 minutes (see [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#time_limits)), you'll be paying for all that time - while likely you'll have very few updates.

The idiomatic way to deal with realtime updates is to let the client [listen directly to the Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data) (or if you prefer [to Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen)). You can secure access to both of these through their [server-side security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/get-started).

The topic of [realtime listeners in Cloud Functions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+realtime+listeners+in+Cloud+Functions) has been covered a few times before, so I recommend also reading:

- [Run a web socket on Cloud Functions for Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45741284/run-a-web-socket-on-cloud-functions-for-firebase)
- [Is it a good idea to run Socket.io on a Firebase Cloud Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56903043/is-it-a-good-idea-to-run-socket-io-on-a-firebase-cloud-function)

---

Note that **Cloud Run** (the lower-level service that Cloud Functions is built on) *can* be used in the way you describe, so check out this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/websockets) if you'd like to learn more. I'd still recommend taking the approach I described above though, accessing the Firebase Realtime Database itself from your web app for the realtime listeners.

Comment: Thank you so so much! I manage to solve it! Thanks again!